# photoshop - managing color themes and switching between them

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

As I build out a user interface in photoshop, how can I assign colors to elements (mainly vector shapes but also text, etc) in a way that I can then create themes and then toggle through them?

In other words, a blue theme that uses different shades of blue and then one click toggle to a red theme where all the elements use shades of red.

I want to be able to set each element's color individually and yet have them toggle collectively as a theme.

How can that be accomplished?

Comment: *"each element's color individually and yet have them toggle collectively"* -- I don't believe that's possible in a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this with "Layer Comps". Unfortunately it doesnt work on "Fill" color on a vector but it does work on all layer styles so a "Color Overlay" works (which as far I understand has the same effect as Fill (well in addition to being more flexible with overlay modes).. please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm just starting).

Comment: You can also do those changes to Blend Options in the Timeline of Photoshop, so stepping through time shows all your changes. And obviously this gives you an animation, if you want, of the themes. And transitions, too.